# Dynamic/complex Questionaire in php

Tags: php, conditional-operator, rule-engine, business-rules

I am looking for a library or framework with the tools that make my life easy when producing a complex questionnaire in php. Has anyone discovered something like this yet?

I am imagining that my questions, their type (single/multiple choice, int input etc.) and possible answeres are stored in a database. I am thinking that the questionnaire is accessed by the front-end through an API where I return the question to ask next, depending on what the user has answered so far.

Depending on the answers to the questions so far, the questionnaire should be able to adjust the upcoming questions. Thus the first feature I am looking for is to store if/then conditions connecting the different questions. This could be considered as some sort of discussion tree or directed graph. 
For this, I have been looking into rules engines like Gandalf, however it seems overly complicated to get the desired result.

Furthermore, I would like to include some previous results into the questions, e.g.: ‘Since you are $AGE years old, how about a beer?’ Before I output this question to the front-end, I would need to check if I have already asked the age of the user, if he is over 21, and only then ask this question, otherwise ask the age first, and so on. Thus the program would have to support some advanced rules and ways to incorporate results into the strings stored in the database.

A cherry on top would be an integrated evaluation tool, logging how many users entered which part of the decision tree.